# Assigning list or array to IRowBuffer Row without Row.set_Value()?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, attribute-table

Is it possible to assign a list or array to IRowBuffer Row?

I have something like the following:
I have a fields (list) with values and i have to fill a Row with that values.

```
public void fillRow(IRowBuffer Row)
 {
  for (int i=0;i < fields.length;i++)
    {
      Row.set_Value(i, fields[i].toString()
    }
 }
```

Is there no way where i can just assign the fields to Row, without looping. What if my fields has like 500 elements and i have to loop 100x500? I know that Row has 2 requiredFields (ID, SHAPE)

Comment: If there was a method that accepted the array wouldn't ArcObjects just be running the same loop under the covers anyway? If I was you I wouldn't worry about how the values are set but about the 1,000 other things that can go wrong in an ArcObjects tool

Comment: Do you mean you want to see how to use a list of field indices?  That way you can avoid getting an exception on row.set_value(0,"") since the OID is usually in that position, and is not editable.  (IField.Editable is false).

Comment: @KirkKuykendall Hmm, i wanted something like this Row = fields[i]. the i-element would be an array or list. But i have to set every column and row individually?

Comment: If the field is a Blob, and the list you are assigning to it is serializable, I suppose you could do it via IMemoryBlobStream.  However, you still need to call set_Value for each field you want to populate AFAIK.